# split sentence without space in python (nltk?)

Tags: python, nltk, spell-checking, wordnet

I have a set of concatenated word and i want to split them into arrays

For example :

```
split_word("acquirecustomerdata")
=> ['acquire', 'customer', 'data']
```

I found `pyenchant`, but it's not available for 64bit windows.

Then i tried to split each string into sub string and then compare them to wordnet to find a equivalent word.
For example :

```
from nltk import wordnet as wn
def split_word(self, word):
    result = list()
    while(len(word) > 2):
        i = 1
        found = True
        while(found):
            i = i + 1
            synsets = wn.synsets(word[:i])
            for s in synsets:
                if edit_distance(s.name().split('.')[0], word[:i]) == 0:
                    found = False
                    break;
        result.append(word[:i])
        word = word[i:]
   print(result)
```

But this solution is not sure and is too long.
So I'm looking for your help.

Thank you

Comment: If your doing word detection, then `tome` might come out of that. I'd say fix the data source that gave you concatenated words

Comment: As @cricket_007 suggested, word detection can be extremely difficult (often requiring machine learning, and AI algorithms) and introduce a whole wealth of natural language ambiguities, your data source should be fixed.

Comment: What they both said. Why don't you explain how you end up with the stuck-together words that you need to split. There's probably an easier way to get where you're going.

Comment: In fact, i just want to clean my data. But i will do it manually if it's not easily feasible.
thanks all

Answer (score 7):

Check - [Word Segmentation Task](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/url/norvig.com/ipython/How%20to%20Do%20Things%20with%20Words.ipynb) from [Norvig](http://norvig.com/)'s work.

```
from __future__ import division
from collections import Counter
import re, nltk

WORDS = nltk.corpus.brown.words()
COUNTS = Counter(WORDS)

def pdist(counter):
    "Make a probability distribution, given evidence from a Counter."
    N = sum(counter.values())
    return lambda x: counter[x]/N

P = pdist(COUNTS)

def Pwords(words):
    "Probability of words, assuming each word is independent of others."
    return product(P(w) for w in words)

def product(nums):
    "Multiply the numbers together.  (Like `sum`, but with multiplication.)"
    result = 1
    for x in nums:
        result *= x
    return result

def splits(text, start=0, L=20):
    "Return a list of all (first, rest) pairs; start <= len(first) <= L."
    return [(text[:i], text[i:]) 
            for i in range(start, min(len(text), L)+1)]

def segment(text):
    "Return a list of words that is the most probable segmentation of text."
    if not text: 
        return []
    else:
        candidates = ([first] + segment(rest) 
                      for (first, rest) in splits(text, 1))
        return max(candidates, key=Pwords)

print segment('acquirecustomerdata')
#['acquire', 'customer', 'data']
```

For better solution than this you can use bigram/trigram.

More examples at : [Word Segmentation Task](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/url/norvig.com/ipython/How%20to%20Do%20Things%20with%20Words.ipynb)

Answer (score 3):

There is a library called "wordsegment" that you can use: http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/wordsegment/

```
pip install wordsegment
import wordsegment
from wordsegment import load, segment
load()
segment("acquirecustomerdata")
```

Output:

```
['acquire', 'customer', 'data']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of all possible words, you can use something like this:

```
import re

word_list = ["go", "walk", "run", "jump"]  # list of all possible words
pattern = re.compile("|".join("%s" % word for word in word_list))

s = "gowalkrunjump"
result = re.findall(pattern, s)
```

Comment: "I have a set of concatenated word"

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a library called [wordninja](https://github.com/keredson/wordninja)

Just install it like:

```
pip install wordninja
```

and use it like this:

```
import wordninja as wn
print( wn.split("thisworkswithnospacesbetweensentences")
```

what will produce this as output:

```
['this', 'works', 'with', 'no', 'spaces', 'between', 'sentences']
```