# A way to separate one word into two separate words using NLTK?

Tags: python, nltk

If we have an unseparated word, let's say
`doctorsofamerica`
Is there an NLTK import that I can use to separate this into

```
doctors of america
```

Thanks!

Comment: is there a reason you don't string.split it?

Comment: Maybe take a look at this previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38125281/split-sentence-without-space-in-python-nltk

Comment: is there a reason NLTK specifically?

Answer (score 1):

If anything other than NLTK is an option, I used to work with [Word Segmentation](https://grantjenks.com/docs/wordsegment/) which gave pretty good results for simple cases. Regarding your use case, it would look like this:

```
from wordsegment import load, segment

load()
separated = segment('doctorsofamerica')
print(' '.join(separated))
```

Output:

```
doctors of america
```